# Angular 2 third party API

Tags: angular, mean-stack, angular-http

I am trying to reach out to an API that works with Postman perfectly fine but does not work in my angular 2 application. I made a test api to http://date.jsontest.com to see if everything with http in angular2 is working correctly and it is.

The error message that I get reads:
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://tsp.touchstream.global/api/rest/stream_enable/a85a58c7/. Request header field X-TS-ID is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

**operations.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Http, Headers} from "@angular/http";

import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()

export class OperationsService {
 listSingleStream(channel) {
    const streamKey = channel;
    const url = 'https://tsp.touchstream.global/api/rest/stream_enable/' + streamKey +'/';
    console.log(url)
    const headers = new Headers({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ********key*********', //private keys
        'X-TS-ID': '********key*********'
    });
    return this._http.get(url, {headers: headers})
        .map(response => response.json())
        .catch(error => Observable.throw(error.json()))
}}
```

**touchstream.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {FormBuilder, ControlGroup, Validators, Control} from "@angular/common";

import {OperationsService} from "../operations.service";
import {Router} from "@angular/router/src/router";
import {ErrorService} from "../../error/error.service";



@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'touchstream',
  templateUrl: 'touchstream.component.html',

})
export class TouchstreamComponent implements OnInit {
    singleChForm: ControlGroup;
    channelInfo:string;

    constructor(private _fb:FormBuilder, private _operationService: OperationsService, private _router: Router, private _errorService: ErrorService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.singleChForm = this._fb.group({
        channel: ['', Validators.required]
    });
}
onSingleSearch() {
    console.log(this.singleChForm.value.channel);
    const channel = this.singleChForm.value.channel
    this._operationService.listSingleStream(channel)
        .subscribe(
            data => this.channelInfo = JSON.stringify(data),
            error => console.log('error'),
            () => console.log(this.channelInfo)
        )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with CORS [Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

If you have access to the server at https: //tsp.touchstream.global/api/rest/stream_enable/a85a58c7/, you can modify its CORS settings to accept the mentioned header field.

But it would be easier to reverse proxy all requests to that server. You can configure your server to proxy-pass all requests to /tsp-api/* to https: //tsp.touchstream.global/api/*. And in your angular2 app, just request to '/tsp-api/rest/stream_enable/' + streamKey +'/'. This way, your request will be of same origin, avoiding all CORS headache

You may want to use nginx or apache2 as your server engine. Those engines handle proxy and reverse proxy perfectly.